# teste PHP off-line

Tags: php

Gostaria de saber como testo meus arquivos PHP **offline**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Veja algumas alternativas:

- [**XAMPP**](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html): Disponível para Windows, Linux e OS X. É incluso: PHP (5.6), Apache, MariaDB, PHP, Perl, phpMyAdmin, FileZilla, etc.
- [**LAMP**](http://www.lamphowto.com/): Disponível para Linux Somente.
- [**WAMP**](http://www.wampserver.com/en/): Disponível para Windows superior ao XP. É incluso: PHP (5.6 / 7), Apache, phpMyAdmin, Adminer,  PhpSysInfo, etc.
- [**EasyPHP**](http://www.easyphp.org/): Windows. É incluso: PHP (5.6 / 7), Apache, Nginx, PhpMyAdmin, etc.
- [**UwAmp**](http://www.uwamp.com/en/): Windows. É incluso: PHP (5.6 / 7), Apache,
  MySQL, PHPMyAdmin, SQLite Browser, Xdebug.
- [Outros](http://alternativeto.net/software/xampp/)...